# Does Symfony need the user to be online inorder to handle messages in the messenger queue?

Tags: symfony, symfony-messenger

I am new to Symfony and I would like to ask this question.

If I have an application that creates a PDF file and emails it to the user when he registers on my Symfony app, and I decide to use the Symfony messenger & messenger queue feature to process the PDF and also send the email, will the PDF file be created after the user registers on my app, irrespective of the fact that the user might go offline or exit the application after registering?

Comment: If you want to email to a specific user, you can pass user id from the controller to the messenger component as parameter